# How to prevent responsive/adaptive skin from shrinking below 360px wide

Tags: responsive-design, viewport, adaptive-design

I'm making a web app I've built responsive. I haven't been able to get some of the screens to get any smaller than 360px wide. But many smartphones are trying to display it at 320px wide. How do make it so it'll be responsive down to 360px but no less?

UPDATE: Prior to posting I had already specified a viewport tag of:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

And, I set a min-width for the container of 360px.
The issue is that in doing this, 40px on the right are hidden when the user first visits the site as IPhones and many others default to only showing 320px even though they are capable of showing more. I know they can zoom out but I'm wanting it to show 360px wide at load time.

Comment: Have you considered changing the viewport instead of the style?  It basically gives a "minimum page width" to smartphones, and can do things like disable pinch-to-zoom (which you might want as well).

Comment: Yes, but I haven't been able to find or figure out the proper way to use it to accomplish what I've described above that will achieve maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

So definately add in the following viewport meta tag in to the head of your html document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

You'll need this to really do any responsive work on phones or tablets.

I'm not sure if you want your width to get no wider than 360px or you are stuck at 360px and want to make sure it decreases all the way down to 320px.

**If you want it be no smaller than 360px...**
You want to have your "wrapper" element be fluid only down to 360px you can set a property on your wrapper div (or whatever element is controlling the width of your site) in CSS to say `min-width: 360px;`. This will make it so the wrapper element doesn't get any smaller than 360px wide.

**If you can't get it to resize smaller than 360px and want it to...** This is kind of the reverse of the above. Maybe your wrapper element has a `min-width: 360px` set. In that case you can remove that property which will allow it to scale narrower than 360px.

Comment: Thanks for the response. See the update I added to provide more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this alteration of the viewport, but give this a try.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, min-width=360, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

What I'm hoping it will do is make the width equal to the device's width, unless the device's width is less than 360px (aka the iphone) in which case make the width 360px.

Your best bet though is to really switch up your mindset a little bit and use a media query to adapt your code for the best presentation at 320px wide. So let your site be displayed at 320px wide but change the css so the site fits nicely at that width.

For instance:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px){
  .wrapper {
     width: auto;
  }
  //change some font sizes
  //put float: none on a few elements that were previously floating
  //change a few widths of container elements to auto
  //etc.
}
```

The css inside the media query will only get applied if the device is 360px or less.

Comment: I adjusted many of the pages so they worked well at 320px but there were some controls that I just couldn't shrink down anymore without a whole lot of work.